# Automake thumbnail

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, images, shell

What I need to do is a program that given (as a command line argument) a directory with more directoreies inside, and 4 Pics inside of each dir, the program makes a thumbnail of the 4 files and glues them together (2 rows, 2 columns) and renames that image to the name of the directory.

I think it could be done with a combination of a program and shell scripting (I'm experienced in M$, but new to linux).

Some real examples would be great.

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look for ImageMagick. [This example](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/#html) should get you going.

Use `find` and `xargs` to run it in several directories:

```
find path -type d -print0 | xargs -0 -i montage ... -size 512x512 '{}/*_orig.*[120x90]' ...
```

`xargs` will replace `{}` with each path that `find` finds. Replace `path` with the root directory in which you want the search to begin.

`-type d` will just return directories.

`-print0` makes sure that spaces and other special characters are handled correctly. The option `-0` to `xargs` is the opposite; otherwise `xargs` would split the the input at every whitespace (tabs, blanks, newlines).

Comment: Why not using the `-exec` action of `find`?

Comment: `-exec` works in this case, too. I'm not sure anymore why I prefer `xargs` - maybe because the same general pattern allows me to run the same command with a single and several arguments.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, Namaste..Ps: long live the command line :)